# Unable to send multiple attachments in Gmail

Tags: gmail, attachment

I attempted to send an email with 14 attachments, with a total of 11.3 MB. Only the first attachment page got sent with the email. Why am I unable to send multiple attachments?

(W7 64-bit, IE9 32-bit, Flash Player enabled.)

Comment: Did you received any error messages or a bounced back email? Also, the upload/attach process was successful for each of the 14 files?

Answer (score 2):

While Gmail allows attachments up to 25 MBytes in size, your recipient(s) email system(s) might have a lower limit.

It is also possible that some of the attachment types are [blocked](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=6590):

> **You can't send or receive the following file types:**
>
> .ade, .adp, .bat, .chm, .cmd, .com, .cpl, .exe, .hta, .ins, .isp, .jse, .lib, .mde, .msc, .msp, .mst, .pif, .scr, .sct, .shb, .sys, .vb,.vbe, .vbs, .vxd, .wsc, .wsf, .wsh
>
> Messages containing the types of files listed above will be bounced back and returned to the sender automatically. Gmail won't accept these file types even if they're sent in a zipped format. Here are some examples of zipped formats:
>
> .zip, .tar, .tgz, .taz, .z, .gz, .rar
>
> **Zip file within another zip file**
>
> It isn't possible to send a zip file containing a password-protected zip file. Please de-compress all files or remove the password protection if possible.